# RAM for Dell Inspiron 3521

Tags: laptop, memory, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron Laptop . It came with Factory produced 2 GB ram and one empty slot.
Now i am not able to determine how much more is supported if i want to upgrade this?

[Manboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvZcC.png)

[Memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbp1D.png)

[SPD - Slot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3si3.png)

[SPD - Slot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkSH6.png)

[Picture of the Memory Slot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMXwH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I am not able to determine how much more is supported if I want to upgrade this?

> ```
> Memory
> RAM                           4GB
> RAM Slots                     2
> Expandable RAM up to (GB)     8GB
> ```

Source [Dell Inspiron 15 3521 Price (03 Dec 2020) Specification & Reviews । Dell Laptops](https://gadgets.ndtv.com/dell-inspiron-15-3521-4769#specs)

Comment: Thanks David. So i can add atmax 4 GB or  6 GB?

Comment: http://www.crucial.com will analyse your system and give you an answer

Comment: @AmitAggarwal - 6 GB modules are not manufactured.  Your system supports a maximum of 8 GB.  Everything you need to determine the answer to your last question is specified by the specifications for your device.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound. My laptop is an old one 2013/2014 model..and the specs mentioned are for the latest one .. So wanted to be double sure..Thanks

Comment: @AmitAggarwal - Based on the age of the components described in that specification it absolutely is NOT for the latest model.  The specifications are for a laptop release in 2013/2014 timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

[According to Dell](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-15-3521_reference%20guide_en-us.pdf) it supports up to 8gb ram

[Your Support Page](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/inspiron-15-3521/overview) should you need it

[image]